# Extracting zip does not store files in "today" in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

I have a Mac OS X Lion 10.7. I downloaded a zip file from the internet which shows up in "Today". However, after extracting the zip file, it puts the contents in "earlier". is it possible to show the contents in "today" ?

This is very unusual because for some extracted files, it shows the files in "today" and other files, it shows "earlier"

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By unzipping the archive you did not modify any file or folder in it, hence the original creation and modification times are used.

In your example the Finder only sees "7 October 2009" as modification date for `jquery-form-validate`.

The only way to achieve what you want is to use a tool that updates all the modification times when unzipping.

In the terminal you could (untested)

```
$ find jquery-form-validate -exec touch {} \;
```